# access to appended/prepended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which has a "phone" field and a button of "add another phone number".

```
<div class="form-group form-inline phone">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonetype1" placeholder="Type of Phone">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number1" placeholder="Write here your phone number">
    </div>
</div>
<span id="newPhone"> Add a phone number</span>
```

When I click this button, another group of fields shows to fill with another phone number:

```
$("#newPhone").on('click',function(){
    var numItems = $('.phone').length +1;
    var newPhone=  '<div class="form-group form-inline phone">';
    newPhone+= '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>';
    newPhone+= '<div class="col-sm-10">';
    newPhone+= '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonetype'+numItems+'" placeholder="Type of Phone">';
    newPhone+= '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="number'+numItems+'"" placeholder="Write here your phone number">';
    newPhone+= '</div> </div>';
    $(this).before(newPhone);
});
```

But then I want to access to these new fields in order to validate their data:

```
$(function()
{
    $("input").on('blur',function(){
        var formElementId = $(this).attr("id");
        validateField(formElementId); //This function works, for sure
    });
});
```

This function is not executed for the new fields. I think this is because the DOM tree is not updated so my jQuery function does not know about these new input fields.

How can I access them even if they are not in the DOM tree? if is not possible, or if it's better, how can I insert my fields into the DOM tree?

Thank you all :)

**EDIT:**

5 more minutes of research and I've nailed the solution

I misused on(), here's how to delegate correctly the blur event

```
$("form").on('blur','input',function(){
    var formElementId = $(this).attr("id");
    validateField(formElementId); //This function works, for sure
});
```

Comment: Read about event delegation at https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You need to delegate the blur event to a static parent so that the new elements will trigger the event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: ... trouble is, blur doesn't bubble, therefore can't be delegated!

Comment: You need to look at [http://api.jquery.com/clone/](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: @Roamer-1888, are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/5Ep38/, jquery works around the blur event not bubbling by using the focusout event

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry I forgot, native focus and blur don't bubble but jQuery maps focus and blur to its own synthetic focusin and focusout internally. The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) says "for consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event delegation is the key, see [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) documentation method

PLUS ..

since blur event does not bubble up, you could try with ["focusout event"](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Doc:

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element
>   inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in
>   that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements
>   (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on focusout. Looks better than blur in my case.

Comment: You're welcome ! And yes you're right, I personally never use blur event `:p`